# Insert Chronoforms in Virtuemar tabs / default.php / Joomla 3.7.5

Tags: php, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I want to put chronoforms inside Virtuemart tabs. You can see the tabs in: 
http://dabur.cl/productos/tipo-de-producto/cremas-para-peinar/crema-reparaci%C3%B3n-nocturna-de-miel-detail.html.

As you can see, the second tab is empty. That's where the form should go. 
First tab: product description
Third tab: Disqus

The contents of the tabs are in a default.php file, but I don't know what is the right syntax to call the form.

```
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

                <?php if (!empty($this->product->product_desc)) { ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane desc fade active in" id="desc" >
                        <div class="product-description">
                            <?php /** @todo Test if content plugins modify the product description */ ?>
                            <?php echo $this->product->product_desc; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } // Product Description END ?>


                <div class="tab-pane review fade" id="form" >           
                    HERE IS WHERE CHRONOFORM SHOULD BE!!!
                 </div>

                 <div id="comentarios" class="tab-pane comentarios fade">
                    <div id='disqus_thread'></div>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                          var disqus_shortname = 'dabur-cl'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
                              (function() {
                              var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                              dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                              (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                          })();
                        </script>
                </div><!-- //tab3 -->

            </div>

        </div> <!--/. products-desc-tab-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Already find out. Virtuemart supports chronoform plugin, so the code is:

```
<div class="tab-pane review fade" id="form" >           
        <?php echo JHTML::_('content.prepare', '{chronoforms6}form-name{/chronoforms6}');?
</div>>
```